# altering a word encoder and decoder to give recognize spaces and punctuation

Tags: python

The 2nd function encodes a word phase and the 3rd one decodes that same word function but it doesn't skip over the spaces and punctuation.

```
def buildCipher(key):
    alpha="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    rest = ""
    for letter in alpha:
      if not(letter in key):
        rest = rest + letter
    print key+rest

def encode(string,keyletters):
    alpha="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    secret = ""
    for letter in string:
      index = alpha.find(letter)
      secret = secret+keyletters[index]   
    print secret

def decode(secret,keyletters):
    alpha="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    clear = ""
    for letter in secret:
      index = keyletters.find(letter)
      clear = clear+alpha[index]

encode("this is zest!!!" , "earthbcdfgijklmnopqsuvwxyz")
#gives me sdfqfqzhqs
#need it to give me sdfq fq zhqs!!!
decode("tdfq fq zhqs!!!" , "earthbcdfgijklmnopqsuvwxyz")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the space character isn't in either alpha or your keyletters - if you don't want space encrypted then add it in the same position in both.

NOTE your code currently ignores the fact that space is in the string to encode but not in the keyletters. It would be a good idea to be explicit about this in your code - check that the letter is present rather than simply ignoring the error.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if `letter` isn't alphabetic? Exactly, it doesn't get added since it can't find it's index in `alpha`. You need to have an `if/else` statement:

```
def encode(string,keyletters):
  alpha="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  secret = ""
  for letter in string:
    if letter in alpha:
      index = alpha.find(letter)
      secret = secret+keyletters[index]
    else:
      secret = secret + letter
  print secret
```